Tag returned text with <h2> using Python and Beautifulsoup where there are Heading 2s present in the original webpage
I'm scraping an article from a website and want to keep the original format of the text as much as possible. My idea is have beautifulsoup return all of the text, and use some Python code to input "h2" tags around the appropriate pieces of text where they were defined as "h2" in the original webpage. But I am having issue in coding this.
Assuming the HTML I am scraping from looks something a bit like this:
<section name="articleBody">
  <h2 id="link-a1b2c3d4" style="color:rgb(18, 18, 18)">Point 1</h2>
  <p>Text on Point 1</p>
  <h2 id="link-a1b2c3d4" style="color:rgb(18, 18, 18)">Point 2</h2>
  <p>Text on Point 2</p>
  <h2 id="link-a1b2c3d4" style="color:rgb(18, 18, 18)">Point 3</h2>
  <p>Text on Point 3</p>
</articleBody>

My desired output is:
*<h2> Point 1 </h2>
Text on Point 1
<h2> Point 2 </h2>
Text on Point 2
<h2> Point 3 </h2>
Text on Point 3*

I have tried the following code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import re
import requests
import os

url = http://www.test.com
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

# Parse HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

# Extract article text and include image tags
article_body = soup.find("section", {"name": "articleBody"})
article_text = ""

# Iterate through each element in article_body
def process_elements(elements):
    global article_text
    for element in elements:
        if element.name == "div":  # Check for div elements
            if "h2" in element.find_all(True):  # Check if div contains h2
                article_text += f"<h2>{element.find('h2').get_text()}</h2>\n"
            else:
                article_text += element.get_text(strip=True) + "\n"
            process_elements(element.children)  # Recurse through nested elements
        else:
            # Handle non-div elements directly
            if element.name == "h2":
                article_text += f"<h2>{element.get_text()}</h2>\n"
            else:
                article_text += element.get_text(strip=True) + "\n"


# Apply the processing function to article_body and its children
process_elements(article_body.children)

print(article_text)

However with the above, while it correctly outputs the text with h2s tagged as such, it is repeating every line of paragraph text.

In your code you are looking for DIVs but in the sample HTML, there are no DIVs. Please edit your question and clarify your question and/or samples.

Sorry I shouldn’t be using Div in my code. It was a case of me trying everything to see how I can get the code to work. I’ll update my original post to reflect.

If I understand you correctly, you want to group <p> elements by respective <h2> title tags. Here is an example how you can do it:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_code = """\
<section name="articleBody">
  <h2 id="link-a1b2c3d4" style="color:rgb(18, 18, 18)">Point 1</h2>
  <p>Text on Point 1</p>
  <h2 id="link-a1b2c3d4" style="color:rgb(18, 18, 18)">Point 2</h2>
  <p>Text on Point 2</p>
  <h2 id="link-a1b2c3d4" style="color:rgb(18, 18, 18)">Point 3</h2>
  <p>Text on Point 3</p>
</articleBody>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, "html.parser")

# find appropriate section (<h2> tags followed by <p>)

out = {}
for p_tag in soup.select(":has(> h2 ~ p) p"):
    prev_h2 = p_tag.find_previous("h2")
    t = p_tag.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n")

    if not prev_h2:
        out[None] = t
    else:
        out[prev_h2.get_text(strip=True)] = t

print(out)

Prints:
{
  'Point 1': 'Text on Point 1', 
  'Point 2': 'Text on Point 2', 
  'Point 3': 'Text on Point 3'
}

